# Li Ion cell charging and thermistors

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, protection, charging, thermistor

I am designing a circuit to charge a small Li Ion flat cell with a capacity of around 300mAh.  I want to charge it at around 75mA to 150mA max in the CC part of the cycle.  It will always be charged in a house/office, so will always be around room temperature during charging.  I notice that some charging ICs have an input for a thermistor and some do not.  Under these conditions, is it recommended to use a thermistor to be really safe?

Comment: Nice to have. For failure detection but 1W is not a lot.

Comment: If you can, then I would. With Li-Ion/Li-Po, it's always better to be safe then sorry. If it's too much of a hassle, then it's probably not mandated for a battery this small. As long as your battery has a BMS board built in for Over Voltage, Under Voltage, and Over Current.